# Android SharedPreferences return null Object Reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have 2 activity and 1 config file in my Android project:

1. LoginActivity
2. MainActivity
3. Config

Here's my LoginActivity code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Defining views
    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private AppCompatButton buttonLogin;

    //boolean variable to check user is logged in or not
    //initially it is false
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Initializing views
        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        //Adding click listener
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        //If we will get true
        if(loggedIn){
            //We will start the Profile Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void login(){
        //Getting values from edit texts
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //If we are getting success from server
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            //Creating a shared preference
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(Config.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF, username);

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();

                            //Starting profile activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }else{
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, username);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling the login function
        login();
    }
}
```

Here's my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        AppCompatTextView name = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.name);
        AppCompatTextView job = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.job);
        AppCompatTextView gender = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        AppCompatTextView born = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.born);
        CircleImageView profile_image = (CircleImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");

        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("MIS");
                    isShow = true;
                } else if(isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" "); //carefull there should a space between double quote otherwise it wont work
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });

        /*mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        */

        //Fetching email from shared preferences
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String uName = myPrefs.getString(Config.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF,"");

        name.setText(uName);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        */
                logout();
            }
        });
    }

    //Logout function
    private void logout(){
        //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        //Getting out sharedpreferences
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        //Getting editor
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                        //Puting the value false for loggedin
                        editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                        //Putting blank value to email
                        editor.putString(Config.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF, "");

                        //Saving the sharedpreferences
                        editor.commit();

                        //Starting login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

        //Showing the alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

And here's my Config:

```
public class Config {
    //URL to our login.php file
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "";

    //Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    //If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
    public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

    //Keys for Sharedpreferences
    //This would be the name of our shared preferences
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mis_app";

    //This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
    public static final String USERNAME_SHARED_PREF = "username";

    //We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
}
```

After I run the project and click Login button, I get this error in logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

The error is in **uName** String, I don't know what's going on here.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Have you tried to manually set the 'uName' String ? and did you check that `username` in the LoginActivity class has a value ?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. Using Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); to show value from username. The value is exactly same as I typed in username textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of getting null pointer exception is that you save your data to MainActivity's SharedPreferences and trying to retrieve from another activity's SharedPreferences, plesase try statement instead of yours.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Where should I put that code? Login or MainActivity?

Comment: Both of them, I mean wherever you define SharedPreferences instance

Comment: It's not working, I replaced SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); both in LoginActivity and MainActivity but the result is the same error I get

Comment: Can you please leave a comment below which is the stacktrace in your adb.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the problem.

1. I changed this code:

   AppCompatTextView name = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.name);
           AppCompatTextView job = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.job);
           AppCompatTextView gender = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.gender);
           AppCompatTextView born = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.born);
           CircleImageView profile_image = (CircleImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

into:

```
AppCompatTextView toolbar_name = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.name);
        AppCompatTextView toolbar_job = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.job);
        AppCompatTextView toolbar_gender = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        AppCompatTextView toolbar_born = (AppCompatTextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.born);
        CircleImageView toolbar_profile_image = (CircleImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

And then added this code just below it:

```
AppCompatTextView name = (AppCompatTextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        AppCompatTextView job = (AppCompatTextView)findViewById(R.id.job);
        AppCompatTextView gender = (AppCompatTextView)findViewById(R.id.gender);
        AppCompatTextView born = (AppCompatTextView)findViewById(R.id.born);
        CircleImageView profile_image = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

Voila! the error's gone.